# How use signature pattern for hooking

Tags: c++, hook, reverse-engineering, ida

I like to replace the static function address:

```
AddressOfHookSoundFunction = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("myfile.exe") + 0x0F3B65; // good: 4406117 (integer)
```

using signature pattern becouse is more flexible:

```
SigScan Scanner;

 AddressOfHookSoundFunction = Scanner.FindPattern("myfile.exe", "\x55\x8B\xEC\x83\xEC\x14\x53\x56\x8B", "xxxxxxxxx"); // bad: 3685831 (integer)
```

but the value is different and work only the static address: 0x0F3B65

here the IDA screenshot:

[image: Function]

[image: Exe file]

Probably I have insert a wrong dump information.

Here the code of Scanner:

```
class SigScan
{
public:
    // For getting information about the executing module
    MODULEINFO GetModuleInfo(char *szModule)
    {
        MODULEINFO modinfo = { 0 };
        HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleA(szModule);
        if (hModule == 0)
            return modinfo;
        GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), hModule, &modinfo, sizeof(MODULEINFO));
        return modinfo;
    }

    // for finding a signature/pattern in memory of another process
    DWORD FindPattern(char *module, char *pattern, char *mask)
    {
        MODULEINFO mInfo = GetModuleInfo(module);
        DWORD base = (DWORD)mInfo.lpBaseOfDll;
        DWORD size = (DWORD)mInfo.SizeOfImage;
        DWORD patternLength = (DWORD)strlen(mask);

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < size - patternLength; i++)
        {
            bool found = true;
            for (DWORD j = 0; j < patternLength; j++)
            {
                found &= mask[j] == '?' || pattern[j] == *(char*)(base + i + j);
            }
            if (found)
            {
                return base + i;
            }
        }

        return NULL;
    }
};
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: `found &= mask[j] == '?' || pattern[j] == *(char*)(base + i + j);` is the sort of code where a few ( ) help for readability - I don't even try to figure out if it's correct. I suppose your intent was `found &= ( mask[j] == '?' || pattern[j] == *(char*)(base + i + j) );`.

Comment: yes, I confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're not differentiating between pointers and integers. The return value of `FindPattern` is a `DWORD`, but what you actually return is a broken address `base + i`. I'm saying "broken" because on Win64 this loses the top 32 bits of the address.

Regardless, since the returned value is an address, it's obvious that this can differ from the offset `0x0F3B65`. And with ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization), addresses can differ from run to run. You probably want to return just `i`, and you also want to remove the broken cast in `DWORD base = (DWORD)mInfo.lpBaseOfDll;`. This also fixes the `char*` cast later on.

That BTW is further wrong because it loses a `const`; code segments are not writable these days. See DEP (Data Execution Prevention) - your hook will need to address that too.

Comment: Thank you probably is better rewrite the code for find the signature due too many errors.

Answer (score 0):

If someone need here is working code for Windows x64 (c++)

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

class SigScan {
public:
    // For getting information about the executing module
    static MODULEINFO GetModuleInfo(char *szModule) {
        MODULEINFO modinfo = {nullptr};
        HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(szModule);
        if (hModule == nullptr) {
            return modinfo;
        }
        GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), hModule, &modinfo, sizeof(MODULEINFO));
        return modinfo;
    }

    // for finding a signature/pattern in memory of another process
    static DWORD_PTR FindPattern(const string& module, string pattern, string mask) {
        MODULEINFO mInfo = GetModuleInfo(const_cast<char *>(module.c_str()));
        auto base = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(mInfo.lpBaseOfDll);
        auto size = (DWORD) mInfo.SizeOfImage;
        auto patternLength = mask.length();

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < size - patternLength; i++) {
            bool found = true;
            for (DWORD j = 0; j < patternLength; j++) {
                found &= mask[j] == '?' || pattern[j] == *(char *) (base + i + j);
            }
            if (found) {
                return base + i;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
};
```